# Best way to find and replace a string format from the html text content using c#

Tags: c#, html, css

I am creating an `Windows phone`  application which is rendering html content on web browser.
I have a css file where i need to alter some values which are in  a special format.
Following is an example of my data, where you can see a number of `'.position-page{n}-{n}'`
style tags there includes 3 properties in each `margin left ,right & top`.

```
</style><style type='text/css'>
 .position-page2-1 {
margin-right: 180px;
margin-left: 180px;
margin-top: 280px;
    }
    .position-page2-2 {
margin-right: 350px;
margin-left: 150px;
margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .position-page2-3 {
margin-right: 180px;
margin-left: 220px;
margin-top: 80px;
    }
    .position-page2-4 {
margin-right: 180px;
margin-left: 220px;
margin-top: -20px;
    }
    .position-page2-5 {
margin-right: 350px;
margin-left: 140px;
margin-top: -10px;
color: #5ED6FB;
    }
      .page2-2 {
font-size: 20px;
text-align: justify;
line-height: 25px;
    }
      .page2-3 {
font-size: 15px;
text-align: justify;
line-height: 20px;

     }
     .page2-4 {
font-size: 15px;
text-align: justify;
line-height: 20px;
     }
      .page2-5 {
font-size: 20px;
text-align: justify;
line-height: 25px;
     }
</style>
```

> We are getting this style text as response from a 3rd party service.

As per our requirement i need to reduce margin's value to some percentage. Suppose if 150px is the margin i want replace it by 30px , i need to replace each margin value in to currentmargin/5 px.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please add more details - do you have control over the creation of the css file in the 1st place, or is it retrieved from a 3rd party?Are you creating a desktop application with a webbrowserControl, or are you making a website that users visit with a browser?

Comment: There is not any math in regex (what you may use to search for that). BIG BUT. If you can use Perl then you can capture regex expressions and use them to build new string. Idea from [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/117098/Regex-Help-for-Adding-14-to-a-Series). Of course you can do same in C# (with regex again, no need to parse CSS), it'll just be longer.

Comment: am creating a windows phone application so that i can't use perl here. If i get it by regex , it will be very helpful.

Comment: @user574632 the style is coming from a third party service response. For making it to fit with our screen [windows phone] we just need to edit it as said it in the question.

Comment: In that case i would consider a CCS parser, such as this: https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS

Comment: never mind - same answer as above.

Comment: But it is not targeting to windows phone when i added it by nuget

Comment: I tried with porting the library to windows phone . But it failed to build succeed because ConvertFromUtf32 ,ConvertToUtf32  is not available with the cahr.

Answer (score 0):

Is that possible for you to use [**viewport**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) scale?

In that case you should not change anything in css at all.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
```

Here is more info about design adaptation, provided by Microsoft:

[Managing the Windows Phone Browser Viewport](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/14/managing-the-windows-phone-browser-viewport.aspx)